# acentos y ñ's fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

Hola estoy leyendo un txt con php y al visuarlizarlo  no me codifica a utf-8 y me da error en comas y en ñ's, adjunto mi codigo donde se ven dos ejemplos donde intente codificarlos sin exito

```
        $buscar=array("*FECHA*", "*NOMEMP*","*APPAT*","*APMAT*",  "*DOMEMPLEADO*","*COLONIA*","*NUMEROEXTERIOR*","*MUNICIPIO*","*ESTADO*", 
            "*SALARIO*","*PUESTO*","*EMPRESA*","*PATRON*","*CALLEPAT*","*NUMPAT*","*COLPAT*","*CIUDPAT*","*CPPAT*","*NACIONALIDAD*","*FECHANACIMIENTO*","*NSS*","*RFCEMP*","*CURPEMP*","*GENEMP","*ESTCIVIL*","*ESTADOEMP*","*HENTRADA*","*HSALIDA*","*FECHAINICIAL*",
            "*DIASDURACION*","*FECHAFINAL*","*CPS*");


        $reemplazar=array($fecha, $nomemp, $apellido_paterno,$apellido_materno ,  $domempleado,$colonia,$numeroExterior,$municipio,$estado,  $salario, $puesto, $empresa, $patron, $calle_empresa, $num_empresa, $colonia_empresa, $ciudad_empresa, $cp_empresa, $nacionalidad,
            $fechaNacimiento,$NSS,$rfc,$curp,$generoemp,$estadocivil,$estadoEMP,$hEntrada,$hSalida,$FechaInicial,$Dias_duracion,$Fecha_Final,$cps);
        $reemp=str_replace($buscar, $reemplazar, $archivo);

                    list($acuerdos,$firmas) = explode("*AF*", $reemp);
                    $convert = explode("\n", $acuerdos);
                    for($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++)  
                    {

                        $saltodelinea = nl2br($convert[$i]);
                        $pdf->SetX(5);
                        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',5.5);
                        $pdf->MultiCell(200,6, utf8_encode($saltodelinea), 0,"FJ",0);

                    }       
                    $pdf->SetX(5);
                        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',5.5);
                        $pdf->MultiCell(200,6,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', " ". $firmas." " ), 0,"C",0);


                    $pdf->Output();

?>
```

Y de esta forma si lee bien el archivo y los datos y todo pero me marca error en las ñ's y comas, adjunto imagen grafica, no se si exista alguna otra funcion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el fpdf interpreta el html sin el utf-8, lo que debes hacer es convertir tus caracteres especiales en html entities, puedes usar la funcion: `htmlentities`.

Prueba con

```
$saltodelinea = nl2br(htmlentities($convert[$i]));
```